# Is it true that surgery for cancer can cause the cancer to spread?

Tags: cancer, statistics, surgery, metastatic-cancer, experiment

[This cancer.org article](https://www.cancer.org/treatment/treatments-and-side-effects/treatment-types/surgery/risks-of-cancer-surgery.html) says:

> You may have heard that surgery for cancer can cause the cancer to spread. It's very rare for surgery to cause cancer to spread. Advances in equipment used during surgery and more detailed imaging tests have helped make this risk very low. Still, there are some important situations when this can happen. Doctors who have a lot of experience in treating cancer with surgery are very careful to avoid these situations.
>
> In the past, larger needles were used to take a piece of the tumor (biopsy) to look at under a microscope in the lab. Back then, the chance of spread or “seeding” from the biopsy was higher. Now, it’s more likely that a small needle is used to remove a piece of the tissue (called a needle biopsy). With the smaller needle, the chances of a biopsy causing a cancer to spread or “seed” are very low. Still, some liver (hepatic), kidney (renal), and other tumors have a very small risk of this happening during a biopsy procedure.
>
> Most types of cancers can be safely sampled by what is called an incisional biopsy, where the surgeon cuts through the skin to remove a small part of the tumor. But there are a few exceptions, such as certain tumors in the eyes or in the testicles. Doctors may treat these types of cancer first, without taking a biopsy, or may recommend removing (resecting) the entire tumor if it’s likely to be cancer. Sometimes, a needle biopsy can be used safely, and then if the tumor is found to be cancer, the whole tumor is removed.
>
> Needle biopsies can’t be used for some tumors. In these cases, the tumor may need to be partially or totally removed. There are a few kinds of tumors that do have a low risk of cancer spread from the resection procedure. Examples include parathyroid and gallbladder tumors, and some sarcomas. However, this only rarely happens due to the advances in equipment and imaging tests.

And [this ncbi.nlm.nih.gov article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5380551/) says:

> Surgery is a crucial intervention and provides a chance of cure for patients with cancer. The perioperative period is characterized by an increased risk for accelerated growth of micrometastatic disease and increased formation of new metastatic foci. The true impact for cancer patients remains unclear. This review summarizes the often fragmentary clinical and experimental evidence supporting the role of surgery and inflammation as potential triggers for disease recurrence. Surgery induces increased shedding of cancer cells into the circulation, suppresses anti-tumor immunity allowing circulating cells to survive, upregulates adhesion molecules in target organs, recruits immune cells capable of entrapping tumor cells and induces changes in the target tissue and in the cancer cells themselves to enhance migration and invasion to establish at the target site. Surgical trauma induces local and systemic inflammatory responses that can also contribute to the accelerated growth of residual and micrometastatic disease.

And [this cancer.gov article](https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/myths) says:

> The chance that surgery will cause cancer to spread to other parts of the body is extremely low. Following standard procedures, surgeons use special methods and take many steps to prevent cancer cells from spreading during biopsies or surgery to remove tumors. For example, if they must remove tissue from more than one area of the body, they use different surgical tools for each area.

But [this acsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com article](https://acsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cncr.21194) says:

> The most prevalent misconception, “Treating cancer with surgery can cause it to spread throughout the body,” was endorsed as true by 41% of the respondents.

And [this 2005 nbcnews.com article](https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna8389850) echoes that, saying:

> More than 40 percent of Americans surveyed in a study falsely believed surgery can allow cancer cells to spread through the body, researchers said. And up to a quarter believed there is a drug industry plot to cover up a cure for cancer.
>
> The survey, published in the journal Cancer, may mean patients with cancer may fail to get treatment or may fail to stick with it, the researchers said.
>
> The telephone survey of 957 adults was designed to represent the general U.S. population, said the researchers, led by Dr. Ted Gansler of the American Cancer Society.
>
> “The most prevalent misconception, ’Treating cancer with surgery can cause it to spread throughout the body,’ was endorsed as true by 41 percent of the respondents,” the researchers wrote in their report.

Comment: Could you clarify what information you are seeking? As you have found in your research, yes, surgery can rarely cause cancer to spread. The risk of spread is undoubtedly influenced by many factors, including cancer type, cancer stage at the time of surgery, the actual surgery performed, and skill of the surgeon. If the question is "what is the risk of surgery causing spread of cancer?" then there are too many factors to consider to provider a specific answer.

Comment: The only question I see here is in the title, and I agree with @IanCampbell that the references you provide answer it. So please clarify what it is you're asking.

Comment: @IanCampbell and Carey Gregory I just want to know which of the two sides is right. One side says it is a misconception that surgery can for cancer can cause the cancer to spread, the other says the opposite. I cannot tell for sure which side is right. Some of the references I provide say one come down on one side very emphatically, the others come down equally emphatically on the other.

Comment: To me, the multiple sources are not as contradictory as they may seem at first glance. The ultimate answer is that surgery can *rarely* cause cancer spread. The last two references are reporting that the general public greatly overestimates this risk and that this misconception may interfere with good medical care. If you [edit] your question to clarify, I think you would be more likely to receive an answer.

Comment: @IanCampbell Could you please explain how I could edit the question to clarify? Why do you think the last two references are reporting that the general public greatly overestimates this risk, when that is not what the references say?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh The last two references report what the _public_ believes, and one of them specifically calls it a misconception. The other references report what science believes, and they all make it quite plain that the risk exists but it is minimal, surgeons are well aware of it, and take steps to avoid it. So the answer to the question "Which side is right?" is pretty plain from the research you provided. Science is right. So can you see why you need to clarify your question?

Comment: And thank you for making an honest effort to answer the question yourself and doing some decent research before asking. +1 for that.